# Pyuic5 generates python files with invalid imports

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt5, pyuic

While using PyQt5 in a project, I convert some .ui files tp .py files using `pyuic5 -x design.ui -o design_ui.py`. In the generated python file, there is this import statement: `from ktreewidgetsearchline import KTreeWidgetSearchLine`, which Python (3.6.1) is unable to find.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04. I have have tried to install KDE, and its development packages without luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Where might I find the proper python packages that are needed for displaying the widgets? Alternatively, how might I configure / tell PyQt / pyuic5 to generate files that can be shown in gnome / unity, or cross platform in general?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could share the .ui file. Maybe you're adding KDE components? If you're doing it, do not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not at liberty to disclose the file. However, you are right. There are KDE elements in it.
It was originally designed in (Py)Qt4, might that matter?

Comment: execute this: `sudo apt-get install python3-pykde4 `

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
It would seem I have to change the design files to use something more standard, since this application is supposed to run on non-KDE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my project and solved it as follows:

- For my project (see [KSP Mod Analyzer](https://github.com/akej74/ksp-mod-analyzer) on GitHub), I have the following structure:

  - ksp-mod-analyzer/ui/mainwindow.ui (UI created by QT Designer)
  - ksp-mod-analyzer/ui/resources.qrc (Resource file with icons)
- Running `pyuic5 --from-imports mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py` added the following import directive to my mainwindow.py

  - `from . import resources_rc`

By this, the import command worked.